# How to control sort direction in a list query in AWS-Amplify with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

I've seen several useful posts on how to create schemas in AWS-Amplify's GrahphQL API package that will return a sorted response. In brief, if you have the following in your `schema.graphql` file

```
type Record @model
@key(name: "byDateCreated", fields: ["status", "createdAt"], queryField: "RecordsByDateCreated") {
    id: ID!
    status: RecordStatus!
    description: String!
    createdAt: String
}
```

It will create a custom query called `recordsByDateCreated`. Using it as follows (js here, folks):

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(recordsByDateCreated, { status: 'unused', limit: 10 }));
```

will return the first 10 records in the table sorted by their `createdAt` values. By default, this data will be returned in **ascending** order, which means that you'll get the **oldest** records first.

However, what I need is a response that has the newest records first. What do I have to add to in schema or my query so I can set the order of the sorting?

Answer (score 3):

**(Spoiler alert: I'm answering my own question here in case anyone else is looking for help with this.)**

You would need a way to order the table's records in **descending** order. If you go and look at the file generated by AWS-Amplify you'll see that the new query you've created accepts a series of arguments:

```
export const recordsByDateCreated = /* GraphQL */ `
  query RecordsByDateCreated(
    $status: RecordStatus
    $createdAt: ModelStringKeyConditionInput
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
    $filter: ModelRecordFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    RecordsByDateCreated(
      status: $status
      createdAt: $createdAt
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        description
        status
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`
```

It turns out that if you know what the possible values are for `ModelSortDirection` (they are are 'ASC' and 'DESC') you can pass one in as one of the variables arguments when you make that query like so:

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(recordsByDateCreated, { status: 'unused', limit: 10, sortDirection: 'DESC' }));
```

(Note that the key for the variable you're passing is `sortDirection` and not `$sortDirection`, or `ModelSortDirection`.)

I couldn't find this in AWS-Amplify's docs and relied on other posts that I've found. If you've found any documentation relevant to this then maybe you could add a link in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment with a reputation below 50 lol so need to make a whole other answer)

As you mentioned adding `sortDirection` as one of the variables arguments allows you to choose the direction, but also if you're looking to sort the items by a specific attribute other than the default one, you'll have to make that choice in the graphql schema model definition.
So for the model `User` you'd choose the attribute in the second key field

```
type User
@model
@key(fields: ["id", "DoB"]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    DoB: String!
    createdAt: String!
}
```

and a query would sort the items by their `DoB`